# I speak without a mouth and hear without ears

Tags: riddle

I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but I come alive with wind. What am I?

This riddle relies on tricking you into thinking about ears and a mouth. You get a tiny hint about wind to encourage you to think broadly and avoid the literal.

Comment: Hi Ajay :) Just a tip: Before posting a puzzle like this you should use the search bar on the site to be sure it has not already been asked (as we don't want duplicate questions on Puzzling). In this case a few keywords brought up a duplicate immediately. Better luck next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

> an echo--------

Comment: Correct! Good job!